# Handle UUID when import from PostgresQL to OrientDB using ETL

Tags: postgresql, etl, orientdb

I have a graph in PostgresQL with 2 table:

- vertex (id:uuid)
- edge (from:uuid, to:uuid)

I use etl to transform it to orientdb for vertex:

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
              "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test",
              "userName": "postgres",
              "userPassword": "123456",
              "query": "select id from vertex" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "vertex"} }
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "PLOCAL:../databases/test",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
      "dbAutoDropIfExists": false
    }
  }
}
```

When browsing the result in OrientDB, it seemed that the value i see in id field is not consistent with the result I got when query in PorgresQL.

Then I run etl for edge:

```
{
  "config": {
    "parallel" : true,
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
              "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test",
              "userName": "postgres",
              "userPassword": "123456",
              "query": "select from, to from edge" 
        }
  },
  "transformers": [ 
    { "merge": { "joinFieldName": "from", "lookup": "vertex.id" } }, 
    { "vertex": {"class": "vertex", "skipDuplicates": true} }, 
    { "edge": { "class": "has_edge", "joinFieldName": "to", "lookup": "Vertex.id", "direction": "in" } }, 
    { "field": { "fieldNames": ["from", "to"], "operation": "remove" } } 
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "PLOCAL:../databases/test",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
      "dbAutoDropIfExists": false
    } 
  }
}
```

The debug printed out console there were some edges that etl processor could not lookup references for `from` or `to`. This kind of message use uuids from PostgresQL. Since they are not inconsistent with the values I could query in OrientDB, it is hard to figure out which edges causing the problem.

My question is: how could I config my etl to make uuid from PostgresQL import properly to OrientDB?

Comment: The ETL seems correct. By enabling a high level of logging, can you figure out which UUID is missing?

Comment: I'm trying to cast the uuid to string in posgresql first to see if the vertex imported properly